# How to create a sticky progress bar for multiple form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form which has multiple sections in it. I am using Html, CSS and bootstrap for frontend and PHP as a server-side language. I am a beginner in this. I have created responsive progress bar but it is not sticky. can anyone advice me that how can i fix it on top i.e sticky? Thanks in advance guys.

```
<section>
    <div class="container"  style="padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;">
        <div class="w3-light-grey">
          <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-blue w3-center" style="width:0">0%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The bootstrap way is using [affix](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#affix)

Comment: can you please give me the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xLf9yn2t/

Comment: doesn't solve the problem sir